# Why does Bitmap.scale not work?

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap, createjs, easeljs

I want to add my image to a canvas, and position and scale it.
I know how to position it, but every time I scale it, it disappears from my canvas.

My current code looks similar to this:

```
function init() {
    var canvas = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

    var image = new createjs.Bitmap("assets/image.png");
    image.scale(600, 600);
    canvas.addChild(image);
    canvas.update(image);
}
```

My image does not appear on the canvas unless I remove `image.scale(600, 600)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Bitmap.html#property_scale), the `scale` property is the scale **factor**. For example, a scale of 2 means that the image is *two times as large*. You're making the image 600 times as large. So a 64x64px image would become a 38400x38400px image. You'll need to calculate the factor from the image's dimensions:

```
const imageBounds = image.getBounds()
image.scaleX = 600 / imageBounds.width;
image.scaleY = 600 / imageBounds.height;
```

Notice also that `scale` is a property, you can also directly assign to it:

```
image.scale = 1.6;
```

Comment: I agree. In this situation, if you want to scale the image from 64 to 600 pixels, `image.scale = 9.375;` would do the trick (scale = 600 / 64)

Comment: @doppl3r Good addition. Let me add that.

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I done: image.scaleX = 0.5; image.scaleY = 0.5;